# Extending BaseRequestOptions to set global Headers for requests

Tags: angular

I have a service that extends `baserequestoptions` to include two headers which are common to all http requests. The problem is that these headers are set in the constructor when the service is instantiated. So, once they are set, they wont change unless a page reload occurs (Assumption: all code, components, services etc get recreated on a browser refresh)

To solve this, I added a `public method setHeader()` which I can call from other components/services IF i can get an instance of `DefaultRequestOptions` so I can call the `getHeader()` method.

Now, I do not know how to get an instance of `DefaultRequestOptions`.
Also, is there something possible using rxjs observables which automatically update the headers in the DefaultRequestOptions class.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class DefaultRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {

constructor() {
 super();

// Set the default 'Content-Type' header
this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
// Set the default 'Authorization' header
this.headers.set('Authorization', 'oh god');
}

public setHeader(header: string, value: string){
 this.headers.set(header, value);
}

}

export const requestOptionsProvider = { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DefaultRequestOptions };
```

Comment: Sounds like you're confusing the *default headers* and the *per-request headers*. Like you said you changed the default headers and that's done. Now you can *always* change the headers for any specific request by passing new headers **at the time of the request**. If you find yourself changing the headers over and over again, then you could wrap all requests in a custom service and set the headers once for a bunch of requests in this service.

Comment: @AngularFrance fancy, but do you think that is the correct way ? repeat the  code in every call. What about create a custom service ? where do the `subscribe()` method? in `myModel.service` or in `MyOverrideHttp.service, can we chain Observables ?, Thank you for your knowledge

Comment: It really depends what you're trying to achieve: Override `RequestOptions` if you need to change the headers for all/most requests in your app. Override the per-request options if you only need to change the headers for a few requests. Creating a custom service is also a good option. In any case, *always* subscribe at the last possible moment (i.e. when you actually need to consume the data), not in the service fetching or transforming the data.